# ContextMenuStrip Event Handler in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to attach ContextMenyStrip event handler to each picturebox created if it's name is "merger".Here are the codes.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public NetworkArea n;
    Components sp1;
    Components sp2;
    int s = 0;
    int p = 0;
    PictureBox pb;
    Merger mg;
            public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pb = new PictureBox();
       // pb.Name = "Merger";
        mg = null;
        n = new NetworkArea();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.AllowDrop = true;

        pictureBox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox1_MouseDown);

        pictureBox2.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox2_MouseDown);
        pictureBox3.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox3_MouseDown);
        pictureBox4.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox4_MouseDown);
        pictureBox5.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pictureBox5_MouseDown);

        panel1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragEnter);
        this.panel1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragDrop);
        panel1.GiveFeedback += new GiveFeedbackEventHandler(panel1_GiveFeedback);

    }


    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var dragImage = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
            IntPtr icon = dragImage.GetHicon();
            Cursor.Current = new Cursor(icon);
            DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);

            pb.Name = "Pump";

        }
    }
    void contexMenuuu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripItem item = e.ClickedItem;
        // your code here
    }
    private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {


        pb.Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);

         pb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50,50);
         pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pb.Location = panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X - pb.Width / 2, e.Y - pb.Height / 2));
        panel1.Controls.Add(pb);

        if (pb.Name == "Pump")
        {
            label3.Text = "Pump" + pb.Location.X + " " + pb.Location.Y;


        }

            if (pb.Name == "Splitter")
            {
                label3.Text = "Splitter" + pb.Location.X + " " + pb.Location.Y;
            }
            if (pb.Name == "AdSplitter")
            {
                label3.Text = "AdSplitter" + pb.Location.X + " " + pb.Location.Y;
            }
            if (pb.Name == "Merger")
            {
                label3.Text = "Merger" + pb.Location.X + " " + pb.Location.Y;
                mg = new Merger(pb.Location.X, pb.Location.Y);
                pb.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
                pb.ContextMenuStrip.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(contexMenuuu_ItemClicked);
                pb.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Change");

                // 
                }
            if (pb.Name == "Sink")
            {
                label3.Text = "Sink" + pb.Location.X + " " + pb.Location.Y;
                pb.ContextMenuStrip.ItemClicked -= new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(contexMenuuu_ItemClicked);
            }

        pb = new PictureBox(); 

    }

    private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;

        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }


    private void panel1_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
    }

    private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var dragImage = (Bitmap)pictureBox2.Image;
            IntPtr icon = dragImage.GetHicon();
            Cursor.Current = new Cursor(icon);
            DoDragDrop(pictureBox2.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);

            pb.Name ="Splitter";

        }
    }

    private void pictureBox3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var dragImage = (Bitmap)pictureBox3.Image;
            IntPtr icon = dragImage.GetHicon();
            Cursor.Current = new Cursor(icon);
            DoDragDrop(pictureBox3.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);

            pb.Name = "AdSplitter";

        }
    }

    private void pictureBox4_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var dragImage = (Bitmap)pictureBox3.Image;
            IntPtr icon = dragImage.GetHicon();
            Cursor.Current = new Cursor(icon);
            DoDragDrop(pictureBox4.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);

            pb.Name = "Merger";

        }

    }

    private void pictureBox5_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var dragImage = (Bitmap)pictureBox3.Image;
            IntPtr icon = dragImage.GetHicon();
            Cursor.Current = new Cursor(icon);
            DoDragDrop(pictureBox5.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);

            pb.Name = "Sink";

        }
    }





    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
        //ImageList il = new ImageList();

        //il.ImageSize = new Size(50, 50);
        //il.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("../../../images/1Merger.png"));
        //gr.DrawImage(il.Images[0], 30, 109);
        //mg = new Merger(30, 109);
    }


}
```

The problem is that one I dragg and drop a merger then it does not have context menu with it but after that each merger will be having contextmenu.Then after dragging and dropping another picturebox (not merger) if i drag and drop merger picturebox again it does not show any contextmenu but after this the rest of mergers have this menu.
Can anybody tell me what is wrong in these codes?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "to each picturebox created" is the problem in this code, you don't actually create any picturebox at all.  You use some kind of mysterious "pb" variable over and over again.  The code is too broken to guess what is intended, somewhat likely that you'll be ahead when you pass the PictureBox object to DoDragDrop() instead of an Image so you'll actually move the PictureBox to the panel.  Or you indeed create a new PictureBox, at least the Name property is useful to check where it came from.

Comment: You can recheck the codes . Now I have uploaded whole class.Picture box is created in the end of DoDragDrop()

Comment: You must delete the "pb" variable to get ahead, it is quite evil.

Comment: Why do you think I should throw away "pb" And what else should replace it.